# Como encontrar o segundo menor valor de um array em python sem usar funções built-in?

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Sou novato em programação e estou com dificuldades em criar um código que retorne o **segundo menor valor** de um *array*, ex:

```
array = [2, 3, 6, 6, 5]
```

retornar 3

Estou naquela fase de praticar a lógica de programação, pois já compreendo todo o conjunto básico da lógica, porém, como tenho pouca prática em aplicar, ainda me esbarro com problemas que acredito que sejam simples, enfim, espero que entendam.

Comment: Por quê retorna 5 se o segundo menor seria o 3?

Comment: foi mal Anderson Carlos, é isso mesmo, tem que retornar o 3, falta de atenção minha, valeu!, kkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def segMenor(numeros):
     m1, m2 = float('inf'), float('inf')
     for x in numeros:
         if x <= m1:
             m1, m2 = x, m1
         elif x < m2:
             m2 = x
     return m2

 print segMenor([2, 3, 6, 6, 5])
```

Comment: Opa, ñ vi certo, corrigi.

Comment: Agora só falta explicar seu código :D

Comment: m1 e m2 vai receber 5 e 6, x = 2, ai ele checa se 2 <= 5, sim, então, m1 = 2 e m2 = 6, ai ele começa de novo com x = 3 agora, até qd x = 6 e m2 = 5, ai cai no segundo if  (6 > 5) e o m2 recebe 5. Dificil de explica pq é bem complexo, mas se vc fizer no papel vai entender melhor.

Comment: oi allan, cara eu não to conseguindo entender como funciona essa atribuição de valores para m1 e m2, como que as variáveis recebe uma função float com strings dentro (não sabia que isso era possível), e como o codigo sabe que m1 vale 5?, pq olhando o código, para mim tanto m1 como m2 somente tem uma função float com strings dentro, como uma função float pode armazenar strings? e como ela pode ter um valor dentro na primeira passada do if se não tem nenhum valor atribuido a variável m1, somente uma função float, pode explicar mais detalhadamente? ficou confuso pra mim.

Comment: boa tarde, m1 e m2 não recebe um número da lista, mas usei o da lista para vc entender mais fácil. Esse inf ( é infinito - um valor maior do que qualquer outro valor , ñ uma string). No começo sempre vai cair no primeiro if, dai x vai receber um valor da lista, ai começa a verdade. Pq inf sempre vai ser maior q qualquer outro numero. Dai m1 vai receber o x, dai ele compara de novo, e assim vai. Ele só usa o inf na 1ª vez, depois x recebe valor da lista.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você pode usar o **SET** para organizar os dados, garantindo a **ordenação** e a **ausência de cópias duplicadas**.

```
    array = [2, 3, 6, 6, 5]
    copia = set(array)
```

O conteúdo da variável cópia é "[2,3,5,6]", ou seja, garantimos que o segundo valor é sempre o segundo menor.

Após isso você pode imprimir o valor desejado da seguinte forma:

```
   print (list(copia)[1])
```