# if e conectivos lógicos

Tags: python, if, lógica, matlab

Preciso encontrar o **menor número** e o **segundo menor numero** de cinco números digitados.

Porém este fato estranho esta acontecendo:

```
#Subtrair o menor numero encontrado do numero digitado
dif1 = n1 - menor
dif2 = n2 - menor
dif3 = n3 - menor
dif4 = n4 - menor
dif5 = n5 - menor

#O menor resultado diferente de zero é o segundo menor numero
print(dif1, dif2, dif3, dif4, dif5)

#O erro se encontra aqui!
if (dif1>0) & (dif1<dif2) & (dif1<dif3) & (dif1<dif4) & (dif1<dif5):
    print("n1 é o segundo menor numero")

if (dif2>0) & ((dif2<dif1) & (dif2<dif3) & (dif2<dif4) & (dif2<dif5)):
    print("n2 é o segundo menor numero")

if (dif3>0) & ((dif3<dif2) & (dif3<dif1) & (dif3<dif4) & (dif3<dif5)):
    print("n3 é o segundo menor numero")

if (dif4>0) & ((dif4<dif2) & (dif4<dif3) & (dif4<dif1) & (dif4<dif5)):
    print("n4 é o segundo menor numero")

if (dif5>0) & ((dif5<dif2) & (dif5<dif3) & (dif5<dif4) & (dif5<dif1)):
    print("n5 é o segundo menor numero")


print(menor)
```

Se eu declaro somente

```
if (dif1>0):
...
.
```

A mensagem do print é executada na tela.
Da mesmo forma se eu declarar:

```
if (dif1<dif2) & (dif1<dif3) & (dif1<dif4) & (dif1<dif5):
..
.
```

Porém se eu declarar a sentença completa:

```
if (dif1>0) & (dif1<dif2) & (dif1<dif3) & (dif1<dif4) & (dif1<dif5):
..
.
```

A mensagem do print não aparece de forma alguma!
Também tentei com `if(dif1!=0)` e outras combinação de parentes e nada. E de todas as formas no terminal não apresenta nenhum erro.

Alguém saberia me dizer o porque?

*PS.: Pelo que me parece este caso também acontece em outras linguagens.*

Comment: Você precisa fazer manual assim? Porque se ordenasse os números e pegasse apenas os dois primeiros você teria os dois menores.

Answer (score 6):

Em `Python` não existe nenhuma *sintaxe cabulosa*!

Você pode usar a função [`nlargest()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) da biblioteca padrão [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html), veja só:

```
import heapq

lista = [ 9, 6, 3, 5, 0, 7, 8, 2, 1, 4 ]

maiores = heapq.nlargest( 2, lista )

print(maiores)
```

Saída:

```
[9, 8]
```

Uma solução alternativa consiste em ordenar a lista em ordem decrescente usando a função `sorted()` e usar *slice notation* para extrair os dois primeiros elementos:

```
lista = [ 9, 6 , 3, 5, 0, 7, 8, 2, 1, 4 ]

lstord = sorted( lista, reverse=True ) # Ordena a lista em ordem reversa

maiores = lstord[:2] # extrai apenas os dois primeiros elementos da lista

print( maiores )
```

Saída:

```
[9, 8]
```

Answer (score 5):

> PS.: Pelo que me parece este caso também acontece em outras linguagens.

Não é um problema na linguagem, mas sim na sua lógica. A ideia que você utilizou é até bem interessante, de subtrair o menor número e verificar novamente o menor entre eles que não seja zero, porém, suas condições jamais serão satisfeitas pelo fato que uma das diferenças será zero.

Para explicar melhor, vamos supor as entradas:

```
n1 = 3
n2 = 5
n3 = 1
n4 = 6
n5 = 2
```

Assim, o menor valor será `n3`, portanto, `menor = 1`. Após isso, você subtrai de todos os valores o menor:

```
#Subtrair o menor numero encontrado do numero digitado
dif1 = n1 - menor  # 2
dif2 = n2 - menor  # 4 
dif3 = n3 - menor  # 0
dif4 = n4 - menor  # 5
dif5 = n5 - menor  # 1
```

Você faz isso justamente com a intenção de procurar novamente o menor número entre `dif1`, `dif2`, `dif3`, `dif4` e `dif5`, que não seja zero. Ou seja, seria esperado que indicasse o `n5` como o segundo menor número, pois é o menor entre as diferenças diferente de zero. Portanto, seria esperado que exibisse a mensagem:

```
if (dif5>0) & ((dif5<dif2) & (dif5<dif3) & (dif5<dif4) & (dif5<dif1)):
    print("n5 é o segundo menor numero")
```

Mas aqui você verifica se `dif5` é menor que `dif3`, que é zero. Em outras palavras, sempre alguma das diferenças será zero e, assim, nunca a diferença referente ao segundo menor número será a menor diferença, o que explica a mensagem do segundo menor número jamais ser exibida. Neste caso, você teria que verificar cada valor de diferença se não é zero, para desconsiderar aquela referente ao menor número; a sua condição ficaria gigantesca, ilegível (mais ainda) e inviável de utilizar.

---

Outra forma seria, como o [Lacobus](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/301155/5878) comentou em sua resposta, utilizar a função `heapq.nsmallest` (`nlargest` para os maiores números):

```
dois_menores = heapq.nsmallest(2, [n1, n2, n3, n4, n5])
```

Porém, essa forma é equivalente a você ordenar a lista e retornar os dois primeiros valores, o que acho que fica até mais legível:

```
dois_menores = sorted([n1, n2, n3, n4, n5])[:2]
```

Ou ainda, implementar uma função que itera sua lista de números verificando quais os dois menores:

```
def retorna_dois_menores(numeros):
     m1, m2 = float('inf'), float('inf')
     for x in numeros:
         if x <= m1:
             m1, m2 = x, m1
         elif x < m2:
             m2 = x
     return m1, m2

dois_menores = retorna_dois_menores([n1, n2, n3, n4, n5])
```

<sup>Adaptada de [Como encontrar o segundo menor valor de um array em python sem usar funções built-in?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247565/5878)</sup>

Comment: Pois é, também fiquei com essa dúvida. Tá com cara de exercício, e se for, provavelmente ele precisa implementar o algoritmo sem suas alguma função existente, assim como a função que você fez

Answer (score 2):

Como está com a tag [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab), segue uma solução usando as funcões do matlab.

Deixo claro que as respostas do [Anderson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/301166/88991) e do [Lacobus](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/301155/88991) estão ótimas e tem uma análise ótima da lógica.

No matlab, você pode ordenar uma *array* utilizando a função [sort](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) e usar suas saídas, com os índices e os valores.

Como o que você quer é os dois maiores, segue uma saida no prompt para tal.

```
a=[7 3 4 5 8 7 ];
[asorted,aindex]=sort(a)

%saida
as =
     3     4     5     7     7     8
aindex =
     2     3     4     1     6     5

%Apenas os dois primeiros 
Menores_valores=asorted(1:2)
Menores_valores =
     3     4 
Menores_indices=aindex(1:2)
Menores_indices =
     2     3
```